# FieldCount from iTable .NET c#?

Tags: arcobjects, .net, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I'm trying to get a message box to display some simple counts of layers and fields. Everything works fine until I add in the code to get the field count of composite layers. Below is the code for my button click event which populates the message box, and the error message I am receiving.

```
private void buttonCountLayers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //count the point/line/poly/raster feature layers
            int groupcount = 0;
            int pointcount = 0;
            int linecount = 0;
            int polycount = 0;
            int rastercount = 0;
            string subfields = "";
            int subfieldcount = 0;
```

`for (int i = 0; i < layercount; i++)
        {
            ILayer pLayer = pMap.get_Layer(i);
            string name = pLayer.Name;
            pointcount = pointcount + PointLayerTest(pLayer); //returns 1 if layer has point geometry
            linecount = linecount + LineLayerTest(pLayer);
            polycount = polycount + PolygonLayerTest(pLayer);
            rastercount = rastercount + RasterLayerTest(pLayer);

            if (pLayer is ICompositeLayer)
            {
                ICompositeLayer pCompLayer = pLayer as ICompositeLayer; //QI
                int sublayern = pCompLayer.Count;
                for (int j = 0; j < sublayern; j++) //go through group layer
                {
                    ILayer pLayer2 = pCompLayer.get_Layer(j);
                    groupcount = groupcount + GroupLayerTest(pLayer2);
                    pointcount = pointcount + PointLayerTest(pLayer2);
                    linecount = linecount + LineLayerTest(pLayer2);
                    polycount = polycount + PolygonLayerTest(pLayer2);
                    rastercount = rastercount + RasterLayerTest(pLayer2);
                    IFeatureLayer2 pFeatureLayer = (IFeatureLayer2)pLayer2;
                    ITable subLayers = (ITable)pFeatureLayer;
                    subfieldcount = subLayers.Fields.FieldCount; //this line throws the error
                    subfields = subfields + Environment.NewLine + pLayer2.Name + ":" + subfieldcount;
                }
            }
        }
        //show all counts in pop-up window
        MessageBox.Show("number of group layers:"+groupcount+ Environment.NewLine +"point layers:"+pointcount+
            Environment.NewLine+"line layers:"+linecount+Environment.NewLine+"polygon layers:"+polycount+
            Environment.NewLine+"raster layers:"+rastercount+Environment.NewLine+Environment.NewLine+subfields);
    }`

ERROR MESSAGE:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in projectname.dll

Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell not knowing what layers you are in your map, but this code: rastercount = rastercount + RasterLayerTest(pLayer2); makes it look like you are expecting an IRasterLayer.

I do not believe you can get an IFeatureLayer from a Raster layer. Try testing for IRasterLayer and skip over it.

Comment: Also ILayer.Valid http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000770000000 - broken layers can mess up good code.. check the layer is valid before typeof(pLayer2) is IFeatureLayer or IStandaloneTable (both support IFields)